# How to Prevent Any Window/App From Opening on Certain Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have three monitors connected via Displayport to my video card.  I also have an HDMI cable connected to the video card that I run to an extractor solely for audio.  Windows 11 detects that HDMI/Extractor as a generic monitor in the Display Settings.  Randomly Windows will open a window and/or app on that generic monitor.  Most of the time I can do CTR+Space+M, or Rt Click the app in the taskbar and select Move.  However, I do find some apps that I am unable to get to work.  I end up having to disconnect a bunch of stuff, reboot and in general spend 30-60min playing around until I get it to open somewhere I can work with.

Is there a way (via app, setting, reg key, etc) to just prevent ANYTHING from opening on that screen?  And the kicker is that I also have two of the monitors connected to my work laptop, so while the trouble monitor is Monitor 4 right now, if I change the screens then it could becoming Monitor 2 or 3.  So whatever solution would need to be tied to the detected monitor, not just the monitor number.